# Getbalance amount 0 aftering generating blocks with bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

[image]

After starting bitcoind `bicoind -regtest -daemon` then i load one of the wallets i created `bitcoin-cli -regtest loadwallet "wallet-name"`. The wallet loads fine but no matter how many blocks i generate to whatever address my balance stays 0.

Answer (score 1):

Regtest halving events are not the same as mainnet they occur much quicker, i had gotten all the block rewards already and deleted that wallet thinking i could mine more in a newly created wallet lol

Comment: Yes halving interval is [150 in regtest](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7efc628539573af4b4a76d93b853cc46e9e52eae/src/chainparams.cpp#L393). You can delete blocks and chainstate directories inside regtest to restart.